# Overlapping semi-transparent divs without alpha adding up?

Tags: javascript, css, transparency, alpha-transparency

Is there a way to have semi-transparent elements (divs) overlap, and have the overlapped area NOT add up the 2 alpha values...i.e. make a seamless overlap?
So if div 1 and div 2 have 0.5 alpha, the area where they overlap would still have 0.5 alpha, and NOT 0.75 alpha.

Javascript?

I have seen sort of similar questions pop up, but never quite an answer that settles the score...

Maybe a certain hack would be possible, like preventing the browser from displaying any other level of transparency than say 0.5?

That would allow to make really nice designs on websites!

Answer (score 0):

You could display a third, opaque div under the second but above the first to cancel out the first div's transparency. It would have the same BG color as the parent of both divs.